# Code for if statement is not executing although the condition is met?

Tags: c

The code that I wrote underneath the if statement- if(noMoreGuesses == 1) -is not executing if guessAmount >= guessLimit. I end up just being able to enter in a bunch of numbers without limit. I'm new to c, so if somebody could point out what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int guess;
    int guessNumber = 5;
    int guessAmount = 0;
    int guessLimit = 4;
    int noMoreGuesses = 0;

    while (guess != guessNumber) {
        if (guessAmount >= guessLimit) {
            noMoreGuesses = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("Please enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &guess);

            guessAmount++;
        }
    }

    if (noMoreGuesses == 1) {
        printf("You used up all your guesses!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You win!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `while` loop condition you use `guess` before it's initialized. Which means it will have an *indeterminate* (think garbage) value.

Comment: The `while` loop only ends when the correct number is guessed. You probably want a `break;` right after `noMoreGuesses = 1;` to end it at that time. https://ideone.com/hMYH7f

Comment: I also recommend you take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. Debugging is also helped by good formatting of the code, like consistent indentation.

Comment: Fix #1: `noMoreGuesses = 1;` --> `noMoreGuesses = 1; break;`

Comment: @RetiredNinja The break; worked, thanks!

Comment: or fix #2: `while(guess != guessNumber){` --> `while(noMoreGuesses == 0 && guess != guessNumber){`

Comment: On another note, I also recommend you learn about [the `<stdbool.h>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) and how to use the `bool` type (which is what `noMoreGuesses` should probably be).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will give it a look, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have used the guess variable before its declaration the problem may occur. The below modified code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int guess;
    int guessNumber = 5;
    int guessAmount = 0;
    int guessLimit = 4;
    int noMoreGuesses = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (guessAmount >= guessLimit) {
            noMoreGuesses = 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Please enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &guess);

            guessAmount++;
        }
    }

    if (noMoreGuesses == 1) {
        printf("You used up all your guesses!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You win!"); 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You removed the check if the guess is correct.